# How to paste a column into other one?

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyr, data-wrangling

I wonder if there is a way to paste a column from a data frame and append to other column,

like this

df

```
A  |  B 
-- |----  
1  |  6
2  |  7
3  |  8
7  |
```

what I want to do

```
A  |   
-- |  
1  |  
2  |  
3  |  
7  |
6  |
7  |
8  |
```

I tried with this code

```
within(df, x <- paste(a,b,sep='-'))
```

but is not doing what I want

Thanks for your help

Comment: You need `unlist` i.e. `data.frame(A = unlist(df))`

Comment: ```with(df, data.frame(A = c(a, b)))```

Comment: Or `stack(df)[1]`